# Save captured image from camera to custom folder react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

So I am creating a simple camera app using react-native. For camera component I am using `react-native-camera` package. So far I am able to capture a photo and save it into DCIM folder using react-native CameraRoll Api `CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll`, but I want to save it in another folder like `DCIM/CameraApp` or in `Pictures` folder. To achieve this I am using `RNFetchBlob` package. I have tried a few ways to create a new file from the uri that is returned by `this.camera.takePictureAsync` but it throws error that the file does not exists. But if I pass that uri to `CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll` it saves it in DCIM folder.

My current code:

```
    const options = { quality: 0.5 };

    const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
    const { uri, height, width } = data;
    this.setState({ uri, height, width });

    CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri, 'photo') // it saves it into DCIM
    .then( uri => {
        // tried this too
        //RNFetchBlob.fs.createFile(`${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir}/newfile.png`, uri, 'uri'); // throws error that file does not exist
        RNFetchBlob.fs.cp(`${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir}`, `${RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DCIMDir}/CameraApp/p.png`);  
        console.warn('uri:', uri)
    })
    .catch( err => console.warn('err:', err));
    console.warn(data);
```

I have tried few weird ways just to save file where I want but in vain. I hope I have cleared my intentions but please let me know if you need more info. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Julien Malige can you please give any insights to the question..

Answer (score -6):

**I am able to create the directory,but i failed to move the images to that directory,however you can check if it helps you.!!
**

```
import React from 'react';
//import react in our code. 
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, 
Alert, ActivityIndicator, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
//import all the basic components we are going to use.
import { CameraKitCameraScreen } from 'react-native-camera-kit';
//import CameraKitCameraScreen we are going to use.
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'

export default class App extends React.Component {
state = {isPermitted:false}
constructor(props) {
super(props);
var that=this;
async function requestCameraPermission() {
try {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,{
'title': 'CameraExample App Camera Permission',
'message': 'CameraExample App needs access to your camera '
}
)
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
//If CAMERA Permission is granted
//Calling the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission function
requestExternalWritePermission();
} else {
alert("CAMERA permission denied");
}
} catch (err) {
alert("Camera permission err",err);
console.warn(err)
}
}
async function requestExternalWritePermission() {
try {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,{
'title': 'CameraExample App External Storage Write Permission',
'message': 'CameraExample App needs access to Storage data in your SD Card '
}
)
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
//If WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
//Calling the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission function
requestExternalReadPermission();
} else {
alert("WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied");
}
} catch (err) {
alert("Write permission err",err);
console.warn(err)
}
}
async function requestExternalReadPermission() {
try {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,{
'title': 'CameraExample App Read Storage Write Permission',
'message': 'CameraExample App needs access to your SD Card '
}
)
if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
//If READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission is granted
//changing the state to re-render and open the camera 
//in place of activity indicator
that.setState({isPermitted:true})
} else {
alert("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied");
}
} catch (err) {
alert("Read permission err",err);
console.warn(err)
}
}
//Calling the camera permission function
requestCameraPermission();
}
onBottomButtonPressed(event) {

if (event.type) {
//const captureImages = JSON.stringify(event.captureImages);

if (event.type == "capture") {

const pictureFolder = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir+'/Optimize/';
const captureImageLength = event.captureImages.length;
RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(pictureFolder).then((exists)=>{
if(exists){
RNFetchBlob.fs.isDir(pictureFolder).then((isDir)=>{
if(isDir){

RNFetchBlob.fs.mv(event.captureImages[0].uri, RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir+'/Optimize/').then(() => {
alert('Image Moved');
}).catch((e)=>{ alert("FAILED:= "+e.message) });
}else{
alert('Some Error Happened');
}
}).catch((e)=>{ alert("Checking Directory Error : "+e.message); });
}else{
RNFetchBlob.fs.mkdir(pictureFolder).then(()=>{
alert('DIRECTORY CREATED');
}).catch((e)=>{ alert("Directory Creating Error : "+e.message); });
}
});
}
}
}
render() {
if(this.state.isPermitted){
return (
<CameraKitCameraScreen
// Buttons to perform action done and cancel
actions={{ rightButtonText: 'Done', leftButtonText: 'Cancel' }}
onBottomButtonPressed={event => this.onBottomButtonPressed(event)}
flashImages={{
// Flash button images
on: require('./assets/flashon.png'),
off: require('./assets/flashoff.png'),
auto: require('./assets/flashauto.png'),
}}
cameraFlipImage={require('./assets/flip.png')}
captureButtonImage={require('./assets/capture.png')}
/>
);
}else{
return ( 
<ActivityIndicator />
)
}
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```